# Using Microsoft Azure CDN with already existing site

Tags: azure, joomla, cdn, azure-cdn

I am fairly new to using CDN but i've found that there are two types of CDN.

1. You redirect your DNS to your CDN and they automatically take over the traffic as a proxy and do the caching and content delivery. No change in URLs and it's basically no work. Even hard to understand if my content is being delivered through CDN (you have to check headers or use website tools that look for it). Good example is CloudFlare
2. You do not redirect your DNS. You give it an origin server, then everything gets copied over to the CDN servers and you content is available on the new CDN URLs.

Now, i have a website with a lot of images. I want to use Microsoft Azure CDN. I created my profile (Standart Microsoft CDN) and created the CDN endpoint. I tested and it works fine
https://xxxx.com/images/example.png

https://xxxx.azureedge.net/images/example.png
All good - my image is there, along wiht others

So what comes next? I have an image (img src tag) for example pointing to /images/example.png. It seems like i need to change it to https://xxxx.azureedge.net/images/example.png

So my website has a lot of images and if i have to go and manually re-do all the img src tags it seems like a lot of work and what happens if i decide to move to another CDN or stop using CDN. So all this leads me to believe i might be missing a point here and not doing this correctly.

Is that the correct way a CDN like this should work? If yes, may i get some help on how can i achieve that with minimum amount of labour? re-doing all my css, js and images to the new URLs? I am using Joomla CSM.

Documentation out there on how to tackle or deal with something as easy as this are unbelievably limited.

Comment: If you don't get any support here, you might also ask at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, i did post there as well. Thanks for the heads up. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/25049/using-microsoft-cdn-with-joomla

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are right. Mainly, CDN services will basically "pull" static content (for example images) from your website, and then serve them from multiple locations (servers) to your visitors from your provided CDN url. For example:

**Your origin url**

`mydomain.com/image.jpg`

**CDN url**

`mycdn.cdnservice.com/image.jpg`

If the URL was the SAME as your existing url, then it wouldn't really work as a CDN now would it. There are often options so that you can use your own subdomain, for example `cdn.mydomain.com/image.jpg`, but it's still a change of URL. Most CMS's will often have options, or at least plugins, to set CDN url for static assets, which will dynamically replace the paths to point to the CDN url. If you have set file paths manually, then these will need to be replaced manually also with the full CDN path.

There are a few hacks like server `rewrite` which might allow you to use the same URL, but this is not recommended to pursue. Generally speaking, using a CDN requires changing url to your static assets.

**Option #2** is to use a reverse proxy CDN service like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn/). This requires changing your nameservers to route ALL your traffic through Cloudflare, and then Cloudflare will work as a CDN for static assets without you having to change url paths. However, it must be noted that Cloudflare is much more than just a CDN, and you can't really control how your assets are cached on their CDN/servers.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. Yes i got recommended an extension that deals with that in a easy manner for Joomla but unfortunately it's only 1 and paid for HTTPS.